# R - change values if not found in list

Tags: r, replace, notin

I am working with a column of employment data. I want to end with the following values:

- Unemployed
- Retired
- Self-employed
- Disabled
- Employed

I have cleaned up all the different iterations of all the values except for employed. I am trying to craft a statement that would do something along the lines of:

If not in this list "Unemployed | Retired | Self-Employed | Disabled" change value to "Employed".

I have been attempting the use of the %notin% function and the replace() function but am missing something. Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE/EDIT:

I got code to work based on the suggestion from @Rui Barradas, but when cleaning up and notating the code I broke something and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. The code below does not throw an error but it is not changing the values to 'Employed' when I verify with `table(df7$patient_employment)`

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
x <- c(df7$patient_employment, "Unemployed", "Retired", "Self-Employed", "Disabled")
x[x %notin% df7$patient_employment] <- "Employed"
```

RESOLVED:

After some additional help it was pointed out that I was utilizing `x` from the example when I should have been utilizing my data names. Being working on this for too long. Time to stretch my legs. Thank you @Rui Barradas

Comment: `dat$status[! dat$status %in% c("Unemployed", "Retired", "Self-Employed", "Disabled")] <- "Employed"`. (Replace `dat` with your data.frame name, and `status` with the column name.) (If this doesn't work, please [edit] your question and provide the output of `dput(head(dat))`. Thanks!)

Comment: @r2evans while i could not get this to work i am confident it is likely due to my inexperience and I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I was able to get it to work with a different solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following answers the question.

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

set.seed(2020)
status <- c("Unemployed", "Retired", "Self-Employed", "Disabled")
x <- sample(c(status, "Employed", "ABC"), 20, TRUE)

i <- x %notin% status
x[i]
#[1] "ABC"      "ABC"      "Employed" "ABC"      "Employed"
#[6] "Employed"

x[i] <- "Employed"
x[i]
#[1] "Employed" "Employed" "Employed" "Employed" "Employed"
#[6] "Employed"
```

The code above is simple enough to not need the logical index vector `i`. This vector was created to make the code more readable but the following is equivalent to the code above.

```
x[x %notin% status] <- "Employed"
```

After the OP's comment, instead of `x` use `df7$patient_employment` and it should work.

```
df7$patient_employment[df7$patient_employment %notin% c("Unemployed", "Retired", "Self-Employed", "Disabled")] <- "Employed"
```

Comment: Can you explain your comment about not needing the logical index vector? Or perhaps edit your comment to only include what is needed? I took it to mean that this should work `%notin%' <- Negate(`%in%`)
x <- c(df7$patient_employment, "Unemployed", "Retired", "Self-Employed", "Disabled")
x[x %notin% df7$patient_employment] <- "Employed" `

Comment: @RetepYarrum I first present a version in 2 code lines to make it more understandable. See the edit.

Comment: I got it to work once and then when I was noting and cleaning up my code I messed something up and haven't been able to get it to work again... I will update my original question with more info